# Already defined in .obj even when using extern and #ifdef

Tags: c++, linker-errors, inline, extern

I have three files like this:

**head.h**

```
#ifndef HEAD_
#define HEAD_

extern int f();

#endif
```

**mycpp.cpp**

```c
#include "head.h"

int f() {
    return 5;
}
```

**myMain.cpp**

```c
#include <iostream>
#include "head.h"
#include "mycpp.cpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code produces a link error:

> LNK2005   "int __cdecl f(void)" (?f@@YAHXZ) already defined in mycpp.obj

If I add `inline` to the function `f` in `mycpp.cpp` the error goes away.

My question is how to get rid of this error without using the `inline` function?

P.S. This is an assignment and I can only modify the `mycpp.cpp` file. So the `#include "mycpp.cpp"` has to be there.

I know it is a bad idea to include `cpp` files, but I cannot change the `myMain` file. It is given this way. And I am not supposed to use `inline`.

Comment: `already defined in io.obj` - Looks like you have definition of `int f()` in some io.cpp file which you dont mention in your question.

Comment: To your P.S., no it doesn't. You're probably just supposed to implement the function in the cpp file.

Comment: @marcinj I fixed that part. There is no other file. That was meant to be the `mycpp` file.

Comment: @sweenish I meant in the assignment they have asked not to change `myMain` or `head` files.

Comment: The question has downvotes because it's bad code. There's generally minimum threshold that has to be cleared, and including a cpp file does not clear that threshold.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad in Visual Studio you usually add .cpp files in a project tree - you see your mycpp.cpp file in the list of other cpp files. Visual Studio will by default add those files to compilation and linking. So if you additionally do `#include "mycpp.cpp"` then you once again add all the definitions which causes linker error.

Comment: @sweenish I get that. But my question was exactly about a way to make this work while a cpp file is included.

Comment: @marcinj thank you. But the question here is how to deal with a situation like this when we cannot change the inclusion of cpp file.

Comment: **You don't.** It's bad code. The way we deal with bad code is to excise it and replace it with good code.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad you say you cannot remove: `#include "mycpp.cpp"` ? Then maybe put it in a named namespace ? like namespace RemoveThis { #include "mycpp.cpp" }. Or rather if-def it out :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule is: **never** `#include` a `.cpp` file. Only header files should be included.

Besides that, `extern` in a function declaration is redundant here. On a *variable declaration*, `extern` marks the statement as a declaration rather than a definition. But on function declarations this isn’t necessary, and the function has external linkage anyway.

Comment: I would hope the assignment isn't written in such a way that the cpp has to be included. The more likely scenario, as much fun as bashing on teachers is, is to assume the student misunderstands the requirements.

Comment: @sweenish Sure but according to the quoted section OP is quite explicit that the `main.cpp` file was provided as-is.

Comment: I suppose we could continue sparring over our assumptions, or have OP clarify. I don't read that statement the same way as you. Might just be me as a teacher-on-the-side, but I would hope that someone *that* inept isn't running a course.

Comment: @sweenish OK, I see what you mean.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The `head` and `myMain` files are given already. I didn't add the `extern` there.

Comment: @sweenish yes it is written that way. The `.cpp` file is already included in `myMain` file and we are not supposed to change that. This is the point of my question.